# How to connect in c# to a server throught a socks proxy?

Tags: c#, sockets, socks

I program a socket client in C # and I would like to add a Socks proxy support but I have no idea how that works would be nice if I find the solution here.

Comment: What have you attempted so far? Questions on this site generally need to have proof of an attempt or what research has been done to solve the issue. Otherwise you'll likely attract the downvotes or votes to close the question.

Comment: Which socket class/library are you using? It makes a difference in how/if you can add SOCKS handling to it. Please show your actual code that is establishing the socket connection.

Comment: I have used the default socks library System.Net.Sockets.

Comment: `code`udpClient = new UdpClient(address.AddressFamily);
      udpClient.Connect(address);`code`